# Criar pastas a partir de informações das células, com o arquivo "teste.txt" dentro de cada pasta criada (VBA)

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

Eu tenho uma planilha com algumas informações, eu preciso que estas informações se tornem pastas e que dentro de cada pasta haja um arquivo chamado "teste.txt"

Em uma pesquisa, encontrei o seguinte código:

```
Sub MakeFolders()
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim maxRows, maxCols, r, c As Integer
    Set Rng = Selection
    maxRows = Rng.Rows.Count
    maxCols = Rng.Columns.Count
    For c = 1 To maxCols
        r = 1
        Do While r <= maxRows
            If Len(Dir(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Rng(r, c), vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
                MkDir (ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Rng(r, c))
                On Error Resume Next
            End If
            r = r + 1
        Loop
    Next c
End Sub
```

Com esse código é possível apenas criar as pastas sem nenhum arquivo dentro, alguém pode me ajudar a completar o código?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Declarar como Integer

Primeiro uma observação:

> **Observação:** Declarar a `Maxrows` e `Maxcols` como Long (`Dim Maxrows As Long`), pois muitos tutoriais antigos utilizam o Integer, que possui 2 bytes e
>   o intervalo de     –32 768 a 32 767. Portanto, se a versão do Excel for
>   maior do que 2007, o programa irá parar após a linha 32767. Já o Long
>   possui 4 bytes e intervalo de -2 147 483 648 a 2 147 486 647. Em que o
>   Excel possui um limite de 1 048 576 linhas.

E declarando da forma:

`Dim maxRows, maxCols, r, c As Integer`

Somente `c` está como Integer, todas as outras variáveis são Variant.

O correto seria:

`Dim maxRows As Long, maxCols As Long, r As Long, c As Long`

De resto o código está correto e funcionaria. Ele funciona com `Selection`, então primeiro o intervalo desejado deve ser selecionado.

### Solução

Eu gosto de verificar se o caminho existe antes de tentar criar a pasta, para evitar erros (O que já ocorre no código com `If Len(Dir(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Rng(r, c), vbDirectory)) = 0 Then`).

Com `ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Rng(r, c)` o caminho do diretório do arquivo Excel está sendo utilizado como referência para criar as pastas.

Segue a maneira que eu utilizo adaptado ao seu código, que não precisa necessariamente estar na mesma pasta que o arquivo Excel, mas o caminho completo deve ser inserido:

```
Sub MakeFolders()
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim maxRows As Long, maxCols As Long, r As Long, c As Long
    Set Rng = Selection
    maxRows = Rng.Rows.Count
    maxCols = Rng.Columns.Count
    For c = 1 To maxCols
        r = 1
        Do While r <= maxRows
            CriarCaminho (Rng(r, c))
            r = r + 1
        Loop
    Next c
End Sub

Public Function CriarCaminho(ByVal path As String) As Boolean

    CriarCaminho = True
    Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    If fso.FolderExists(path) Then
        Exit Function
    Else
        On Error GoTo DeadInTheWater
        fso.CreateFolder path
        Exit Function
    End If

DeadInTheWater:
    MsgBox "A folder could not be created for the following path: " & path & ". Check the path name and try again."
    CriarCaminho = False
    Exit Function

End Function
```

#### Referência

Para utilizar o `Scripting.FileSystemObject`, a referência deve ser adicionada no VBE.

Em **Ferramentas -> Referências...**

Adicione o 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime'

[image: Adicionar a referência]

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Por algum motivo travou o Excel  mas deve ser hardware kk

O código abaixo funcionou.

Answer (score 1):

Acrescentei a sub geraArqTXT abaixo do seu código, basicamente, essa sub cria uma nova planilha e a salva em formato de texto. Dentro do seu código, chamei a sub, enviando o nome da pasta concatenado com o nome do arquivo (e uma '\').

```
Sub MakeFolders()
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim maxRows, maxCols, r, c As Integer
    Set Rng = Selection
    maxRows = Rng.Rows.Count
    maxCols = Rng.Columns.Count
    For c = 1 To maxCols
        r = 1
        Do While r <= maxRows
            If Len(Dir(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Rng(r, c), vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
                MkDir (ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Rng(r, c))
                filename = (ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Rng(r, c)) & "\teste.txt" 'sua pasta + teste.txt
                geraArqTXT filename 'passando pra função
                On Error Resume Next
            End If
            r = r + 1
        Loop
    Next c
End Sub

Public Sub geraArqTXT(fn As String)


    Dim work As Workbook
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Set work = Workbooks.Add 'cria uma nova planilha
    Set sht = work.Worksheets.Add 'cria uma nova pasta


sht.SaveAs fn, xlTextPrinter 'salva sua pasta de trabalho como texto no destino recebido (fn)

work.Close SaveChanges:=True
    Set work = Nothing



End Sub
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

O código no início deu erro mas depois acrescentei () que faltou em filename e deu super certo.